# SQL : Conditional result used in the same conditional outputs

Tags: mysql, sql

I wondering how to process a SQL comparision without redo the same query twice in the statement.
Here is what I am looking for :

```
SELECT columnName10,
IF( SELECT columnName20 
    FROM OtherExampleTable 
    WHERE id = 15 IS NULL, 'nothing', SELECT columnName20 
                                      FROM OtherExampleTable 
                                      WHERE id = 15
   ) AS AliasColumn 
FROM ExampleTable
```

As you can see, the query **SELECT columnName20 FROM OtherExampleTable WHERE id = 15** is made 2 times.

How could I do the same thing whithout the duplicate query ?

Thank you guys.

Comment: Do you want it because of readability / maintainability, or because of performance?

Comment: because doing useless programming is evil for me :) 

so performance I guess.

Comment: Do you have actual performance issues? Because if so, try to find the bottleneck and fix that. Very often it is not where you think it is. If you do not have performance issues, don't try to fix them. [Remember the rules on optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RulesOfOptimization). That being said, optimizing this for readability *is* a good idea, so you have to change only one part if for example the `WHERE` clause of your subquery changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
SELECT column10, COALESCE(
   (SELECT columnName10 
   FROM OtherExampleTable WHERE id=15), 'nothing') 
FROM ExampleTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
SELECT columnName10,
IFNULL(SELECT columnName20
    FROM OtherExampleTable 
    WHERE id = 15 LIMIT 1,'nothing') AS AliasColumn      
FROM ExampleTable;
```

in this query also write `LIMIT 1` if `id` is not `primary key`

Comment: Wouldn't this make `AliasColumn` `NULL` if the record with `id=15` does not exist?

Comment: @BartFriederichs thanks... i understood what problem will be occur i am changing my query

Comment: Well, reading OP's question again, it seems his query does that too. Don't know if it is the wanted behaviour though.

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions.

> Using IFNULL()

```
SELECT columnName10,
IFNULL( SELECT columnName20 
        FROM OtherExampleTable 
        WHERE id = 15, 'nothing' ) AS AliasColumn 
FROM ExampleTable
```

> Use user variable

```
SELECT columnName10,
IF( @value IS NULL, 'nothing', @value:=(SELECT columnName20 
                                        FROM OtherExampleTable 
                                        WHERE id = 15)
   ) AS AliasColumn 
FROM ExampleTable
```